# Save file to s3 location after selenium/web driver click option

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, selenium, selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda

In one of my use cases, I am trying to get the currency data from a website and then download the daily currency rates which will be further used for conversation activity. Now using the below piece of code, I am able to download the file to my local. My end goal is to run this every day so I was thinking to have a scheduled lambda function and save it to a S3 bucket. Now I am new to all this and usage of various services hence wanted to get some inputs-

> 1. How can I store the file which I get after the button.click() operation to S3 bucket?
> 2. Once this is storing to S3, how can this be put in a lambda function? As this will have selenium and would need chrome driver as dependency**

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/user1/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe') 
browser.delete_all_cookies()   
browser.get('https://www.bcu.gub.uy/Estadisticas-e-Indicadores/Paginas/Cotizaciones.aspx') 
b1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[6]/div/div/div/div/section/div/span/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/input').click() #I am selecting a checkmark here from the menu
button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[6]/div/div/div/div/section/div/span/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/input')
button.click()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> How can I store the file which I get after the button.click() operation to S3 bucket?

Use AWS SDK for Python (Boto3) to upload the file to S3.

> Once this is storing to S3, how can this be put in a lambda function? As this will have selenium and would need chrome driver as dependency**

You can try running headless Chrome in AWS Lambda. https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome